# Prevent question "Restart services during package upgrades without asking?"

Tags: updates

I am actually using Ubuntu MATE 18.04.2, but I believe that the "Software Updater" tool is the same for all Ubuntus, or at least it behaves very much the same.

I have trained my users (friends, relatives and so on) to update their Ubuntu systems at regular intervals, or at least to allow the automatic update when the corresponding notification comes up. I myself do this with my computers in the same way.

In the last months, I have noticed that the update often stops halfway through and asks the following question:

"Restart services during package upgrades without asking?"

I do not really want to invest my time in trying to explain what that question means. I myself find it pretty annoying: I tend to start the update process before my lunch break, so when I come back I can inspect any warnings. Restarting the PC after the update is the only task left. But the silly box has not actually updated, it is forever waiting for the answer to that question.

How can I prevent that question during the update? These are all desktop PCs, where stopping and restarting services has no important impact on the network.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Found an answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543706

In short:

Set no-asking for all packages (solved it for me):

```
echo '* libraries/restart-without-asking boolean true' | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!